# Which war was referenced by Aravind when he said nine countries attacked one country?

Tags: dialogue, reference, 7-aum-arivu

*[7-aum-arivu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7aum_Arivu)* is an Indian Science fiction martial arts film. It was originally made in Tamil and dubbed to Telugu as *Seventh Sense*.

Aravind (Suriya) and Subha (Shruti Hassan) escape from Dong Lee after they are attacked by hypnotized people. Aravind wants to take revenge on Dong Lee and China for sending him for waging a biological war. Subha tries to pacify him saying he is too powerful. While they talk, a war where nine countries attacked one is referenced.

> Aravind : You said our nation is one which showed others what is courage. Now we are facing defeats in the hands of every nation. We should retaliate. He should leave this country alive (emphasis mine).
>
> Subha : No Aravind. He is too powerful. We can't win fighting him.
>
> Aravind : Yeah, we can't win. This is why we have given up our courage along with antiques in the museum itself. We should revive it.
>
> Subha : Aravind, first know in which situation we are in. Our neighbouring country has waged a war going for courage. Did they win? They died.
>
> Aravind : Know the difference between courage and deceit. **Nine countries teaming up against only one nation** and fighting war... is not courage. It's deceit.

Both Aravind and Subha talk about this war. The film is set in India. So, the neighbouring country should be an Asian country. But when I tried googling, a search suggestion was showing "9 countries attacked India"

In which war did alliance of nine countries wage a war on one country? Which war is referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

China and India share a border and fought a border war.

In the Boxer Rebellion of 1899-1901 the "Boxers", a Chinese nationalist group, attacked foreigners in China. The Chinese government supported them.

A bunch of foreign countries joined forces to Invade China and defeat the "Boxers" and the Chinese army.

The Eight Nation Alliance against the Boxers and the Chinese government included:

1) The British Empire

2) Russia

3) Japan

4) France

5) Germany

6) The United States

7) Italy

8) Austria-Hungary

A ninth country, The Netherlands, sent three cruisers to  protect its citizens in Shanghai.

The Qing dynasty declared war on Belgium and Spain, among other countries, but the only Spanish and Belgium troops who fought were guards at their embassies in Beijing.

The Boxer Rebellion could be considered the first world war, despite the fact that there were not millions of people slaughtered. The majority of the people of the world were citizens, nationals, or colonial subjects of the various states involved in the conflict.  Britain, France, and the Netherlands had small colonies in South America, so every inhabited continent was involved.  So the Boxer Rebellion could be considered a war of China against the entire rest of the world with only minor exaggeration.

So it is possible that the Boxer Rebellion is the conflict discussed by Subha and Aravind.